# Good python libraries for encrypting files of different types

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, aes

I am encrypting files in a file server project and I want to be able to choose between different encryption algorithms. So what are some good different python libraries for encrypting files?

At the moment I have used pyAesCrypt there is nothing wrong with Aes but I don't know if there is a better library.

would love some recommendation

Comment: Library recommendation requests are off-topic on this site.

Comment: Both [Pycryptodome](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and [Cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) have Chacha20-Poly1305, a symmertic AEAD stream cipher that is considered equivalen to AES-GCM, in terms of security.